# Is it possible to import a list of Users from Azure AD to populate a custom list in Sharepoint online 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-365-developer

Looking to create a "Terms of Use" page in Sharepoint 2013.

Have decided to create a list containing the users and a Yes/no check as a boolean flag.

Is it possible to automically populate the list with the default value "no" for the boolean but just entering the email addresses of everyone in Active Directory as a simple process to populate the list rather than manually inputting each individual user.

Answer (score 1):

I searched high and low for an answer to this one also, but to no avail. The closest I can get is to show a list of all users through the following link:

https://YOURSITE.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0

Thereafter, you can change from detail to list view.

I haven't experimented, but this *seems* to function like a normal list; You can add columns, views etc. Perhaps this can meet your need?

Good luck!

Comment: Can I save a copy of this with a list view and work off of it from a different directory?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you phrase it another way?

>>Can I save a copy of this with a list view
It already is a list view..

>>work off of it from a different directory
?